# Como verificar se existe um dado no storage

Tags: html5

Olá, Estou usando a biblioteca store.js para facilitar e eu gostaria de saber como eu posso fazer para verificar se exite uma chave no storage.

muito obrigado pela atenção e Boa noite :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`store#get()`](https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js/#storejs) retorna o valor da respectiva chave, se existir, do contrário esse valor será *undefined*. Então pode usá-la para verificar se há algo definido para uma determinada chave:

```js
if(store.get('chave')){
   // Existe.
}
```

Criei um exemplo no jsfiddle pois os *snippets* aqui no StackOverflow não permitem o uso de *storage*:

#### [Exemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/tnwtru9f/1/).

Comment: Obrigado parceiro, matou minha duvida ! :D